# Getting next Timestamp Value

Tags: python, pandas

What is the proper solution in pandas to get the next timestamp value?

I have the following timestamp:

```
Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')
```

I want to get this as the result for the next timestamp value:

```
Timestamp('2017-12-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')
```

**Edit:**

I am working with multiple frequencies (1min, 5min, 15min, 60min, D, W-SUN, MS).

Is there a generic command to get next value?

Is the best approach to build a function that behaves accordingly to each one of the frequencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General solution is convert strings to `offset` and add to timestamp:

```
L = ['1min', '5min', '15min', '60min', 'D', 'W-SUN', 'MS']

t = pd.Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')

t1 = [t + pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset(x) for x in L]
print (t1)
[Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:01:00', freq='MS'), 
 Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:05:00', freq='MS'),
 Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:15:00', freq='MS'), 
 Timestamp('2017-11-01 01:00:00', freq='MS'),
 Timestamp('2017-11-02 00:00:00', freq='MS'), 
 Timestamp('2017-11-05 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2017-12-01 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael :)

Comment: oops, I have no idea. So rather remove it.

Comment: I did update the original post, could you please take a look at it?

Comment: great! I will understand what you did and then implement it in my code.  thank you!